# Why doesn't my if statement with backticks work properly?

Tags: bash, if-statement, backticks

I am trying to make a Bash script where the user will be able to copy a file, and see if it was successfully done or not. But every time the copy is done, properly or not, the second output "copy was not done" is shown. Any idea how to solve this?

```
if [ `cp -i $files $destination` ];then
        echo "Copy successful."
else
        echo "Copy was not done"
fi
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you want is

```
if cp -i "$file" "$destination"; then #...
```

[Don't forget the quotes.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16303/what-is-the-significance-of-single-and-double-quotes-in-environment-variables)

---

You version:

```
if [ `cp -i $files $destination` ];then #..
```

will always execute the `else` branch.

The **if** statement in the shell takes a command.
If that command succeeds (returns `0`, which gets assigned into `$?`), then the condition succeeds.

If you do `if [ ... ]; then`, then it's the same as
`if test ... ; then` because `[ ]` is syntactic sugar for the [test](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest) command/builtin.

In your case, you're passing the result of the **stdout*** of the `cp` operation as an argument to `test`

The **stdout** of a `cp` operation will be empty (`cp` generally only outputs errors and those go to **stderr**). A `test` invocation with an empty argument list is an error. The error results in a nonzero exit status and thus you always get the `else` branch.

---

*the `$()` process substitution or the backtick process substitution slurp the **stdout** of the command they run

Answer (score 5):

With back ticks you are testing the output of the cp command, not its status.  You also don't need the test command (square brackets) here.

Just use:

```
if cp ... ; then
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to testing the *output* verses *status* as correctly pointed out in the other answer, you can make use of a *compound command* to do exactly what your are attempting, without requiring the full `if ... then ... else ... fi` syntax. For example:

```
cp -i "$files" "$destination" && echo "Copy successful." || echo "Copy was not done"
```

Which essentially does the exact same thing as the `if` syntax. Basically:

```
command && 'next cmd if 1st succeeded'
```

and

```
command || 'next cmd if 1st failed'
```

You are simply using `command && 'next cmd if 1st succeeded'` as the `command` in `command || 'next cmd if 1st failed'`. Together it is simply:

```
command && 'next cmd if 1st succeeded' || 'next cmd if 1st failed'
```

**Note:** make sure to always quote your variables to prevent *word-splitting*, and *pathname expansion*, etc...

Comment: Just for completeness `X && Y || Z` is not actually a ternary operator in the shell. `Z` can run even if `X` succeeds (if `Y` fails).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
                cp -i $files $destination
                #check return value $? if cp command was successful
                if [ "$?" == "0" ];then
                        echo "Copy successful."

                else
                        echo "Copy was not done"
                fi
```

Comment: `if cp -i "$file" "destination"; then #...`