# grep and process substitution

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to use process substitution with grep as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [grep -c "*" <(cut -d"," -f5 input_q1.csv) ]
then
  echo "Yes";
else
  echo "No";
fi
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
line 2: [grep: command not found
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you just want to `echo` a message depending on whether any `*` are found, or is your requirement more complex?

Answer (score 1):

`[ ... ]` is not part of the syntax of an if-statement; rather, `[` (also called `test`) is a Bash built-in command that is very commonly used as the test-command in an if-statement.

In your case, your test-command is `grep` rather than `[`, so you would write:

```
if grep -c "*" <(cut -d"," -f5 input_q1.csv) ; then
```

Additionally, there's no real reason to use process substitution here. The overall result of a pipeline is the result of the final command in the pipeline; and grep supports reading from standard input. So you can write:

```
if cut -d"," -f5 input_q1.csv | grep -c "*" ; then
```

to support a wider range of systems.

(Incidentally, the quotation marks around the `,` don't do anything: `-d","` means `-d,` means `"-d,"`. If your goal is to "highlight" the delimiter, or set it off in some way, then it might make more sense to split it into a separate argument: `-d ,`. But that's a matter of preference.)

Comment: Note that `grep "*"` is valid; it looks for the asterisk character.  When there isn't anything for it to repeat zero or more times, the asterisk `*` stands for itself.  Experiment with `grep '*' *.c` or `grep '* ' *.c` (assuming you have some C code with comments in it lying around).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Whoops, you're right. The spec [says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_03), "The <asterisk> shall be special except when used: • In a bracket expression • As the first character of an entire BRE (after an initial `'^'`, if any) • As the first character of a subexpression (after an initial `'^'`, if any); see BREs Matching Multiple Characters". Will fix, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
if cut -d"," -f5 input_q1.csv | grep -c "*"; then
```

... and you'll need to change `*` into a valid regex, because `*` most certainly isn't.

As I've explained in [Why doesn't my if statement with backticks work properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624520/why-doesnt-my-if-statement-work-properly-in-bash/34624704#34624704),
`if` in `shells` takes a command.

`[` is a way to invoke the `test` command -- it's NOT like the parentheses that `if` takes in other languages.

Comment: Note that `grep "*"` is valid; it looks for the asterisk character.  When there isn't anything for it to repeat zero or more times, the asterisk `*` stands for itself.  Experiment with `grep '*' *.c` or `grep '* ' *.c` (assuming you have some C code with comments in it lying around).